# disable share notifications in drive_share() from googledrive() package in R

Tags: r, google-drive-api

I am using the googledrive() package in R to write a data frame to a google sheet and then share with a specific person. Is there a way to prevent that person from receiving an email notification that the file has been shared with them?

I haven't been able to find any documentation to try.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set `sendNotificationEmail = FALSE`. For example:

```r
file %>%
  drive_share(
    role = "writer",
    type = "user",
    emailAddress = "carol@example.com",
    sendNotificationEmail = FALSE
  )
```

See the documentation here: https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/reference/drive_share.html

which links to this doc showing the options you can add: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/create